# Making a table with random colored numbers

Tags: javascript, html

With this html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bonoloto</title>
<script src="bonoloto.js"></script>
<style>
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    td{border: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; width: 6%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    tables();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this javascript:

```
var counter = 0;
var nr1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1),
nr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1),
nr3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1),
nr4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1),
nr5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1);

document.write("Numbers: "+nr1+" "+nr2+" "+nr3+" "+nr4+" "+nr5);

function tables(){

document.write("<table>");
         for(i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
                if(counter == 10) {
                    counter = 0;
                    document.write("<tr>");
                }
                if(i==nr1){
                    document.write("<td style='background-color: cadetblue'>" + i + "</td>");
                }else{
                    document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
                }

                if(counter == 10) {
                    counter = 0;
                    document.write("</tr>");
                }
                counter++;
            }

document.write("</table>");
}
```

This is the output:

[image: colored table]
I must highlight all the numbers like 25 is highlighted. Numbers are randomly generated and the aim is to highlight them in the table. I get stuck in here:

```
                if(i==nr1){
                    document.write("<td style='background-color: cadetblue'>" + i + "</td>");
                }else{
                    document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
                }
```

If i place more if statements the table columns will "Multiply". I cant get that condition working properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `nrX`s, use an array of five random numbers. Then in `if`, check, if the array contains `i`. Something like this:

```js
var counter = 0,
    randoms = [],
    n;
for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    randoms.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
}

function tables(){  
    document.write("<table>");
    for(var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        if(counter == 10) {
            counter = 0;
            document.write("<tr>");
        }
        if (randoms.indexOf(i) > -1) {
            document.write("<td style='background-color: cadetblue'>" + i + "</td>");
        } else {
            document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
        }
        if (counter == 10) {
            counter = 0;
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
        counter++;
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
tables();
```

Notice, that `document.write` is considered as a bad practice, use some DOM manipulation methods instead. In your case [HTMLTableElement Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) seems to be suitable.

You can improve the code, since now it's possible to get doubled random numbers to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var counter = 0;
var randomNumbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
 randomNumbers.push( Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
};
document.write("Numbers: ");
for (var i = randomNumbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 document.write(randomNumbers[i]+", ");
};

function tables(){

 document.write("<table>");
 for(i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
  var found = false;
  if(counter == 10) {
   counter = 0;
   document.write("<tr>");
  }

  for (var j = randomNumbers.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
   if(i == randomNumbers[j]){
    document.write("<td style='background-color: cadetblue'>" + i + "</td>");
    found = true;
    break;
   }
  };
  if(!found){
   document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
  }

  if(counter == 10) {
   counter = 0;
   document.write("</tr>");
  }
  counter++;

 }

 document.write("</table>");
}
tables();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JQUERY** (as you can see makes things much simpler)**:**

```
  var colors=['red','yellow','blue','green'];
  var i;
  $("#container").append("<table></table>");
  var tds="";
  for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
    if(i%10 == 0){
      tds+="<td style='background:"+colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)%4]+"'>"+i+"</td>"
      $("table").append("<tr>"+tds+"</tr>");
      tds="";
    }
    else{
      tds+="<td style='background:"+colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)%4]+"'>"+i+"</td>";
    }
  }
```

**CSS:**

```
table,td{
    border:solid 1px;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    width:6%;
}
```

[Live FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/24kLu64q/2/).